# How to call a method from another class with a simple button in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to call a method from another class with a simple button in my storyboard.
Here are my files:

ViewController.m

```
//  ViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PrintHello.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSObject>{

PrintHello *printMessage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) PrintHello *printMessage;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
//  ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize printMessage;


- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"ViewDidLoad loaded");
}


- (IBAction)Button01:(id)sender{

self.printMessage = [[PrintHello alloc] init]; // EDIT: THIS LINE WAS MISSING NOW IT WORKS

[self.printMessage Print];
NSLog(@"Button01 Pressed");    
}
@end
```

PrintHello.h

```
//  PrintHello.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PrintHello : NSObject
-(void) Print;
@end
```

PrintHello.m

//  PrintHello.m

```
#import "PrintHello.h"
@implementation PrintHello 

-(void)Print{ NSLog(@"Printed");}

@end
```

And also in the storyBoard there is a Button01 linked to the Viecontroller.
From the Log i know that:

viewDidLoad is loaded
and the button is pressed when is pressed :)
BUT the method Print is not called?

Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: I never worked on storyboard before, but I didn't saw your Action method declaration in your header file (it's definition in implementation), also if it's not storyboard, you will need to link the event of button to this Action too. I don't know storyboard how to handle this..hope it helps

Comment: I believe he's saying he's got it all hooked up correctly, and that both "ViewDidLoad loaded" and "Button01 Pressed" is being displayed within the console.  Just that "Printed" isn't appearing in the console.

Comment: Highrule understood, it's like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you call `[self.printMessage Print];`, I think you need to put `self.printMessage = [[PrintHello alloc] init];`.

Comment: Do you get any warnings when you compile?

Answer (score 0):

As woz has said, you haven't initialized printMessage yet, so the object doesn't exist yet!  You probably want to initialize it within viewDidLoad of your ViewController.m file, rather than reinitialize the object over and over again within the button click.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.printMessage = [[PrintHello alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"ViewDidLoad loaded");
}
```